# I deleted CFBundleDocumentType. But the files are stil connected

Tags: ios, share, share-extension, cfbundledocumenttypes

First built a app that support 'public.data' uti. I set the CFBundleDocumentTypes flag in plist. After installation i opened my app from the ios default file app by"Open in". It works fine.

But after testing, i removed CFBundleDocumentTypes and I thought my app would not showing in "open in" options. But even i delete CFBundleDocumentTypes, the file once opened by my app still showing "open in" to my app.

Please let me know the way to unregister(cancel) support file types.

Once connected, the file remains connected even after app removal / device reboot.

I removed CFBundleDocumentTypes, and remove the app.
And reboot device, install my app again(without CFBundleDocumentTypes)

But some files still showing "open in" option.